# Check if all the columns are present using ADF without Dataflow because the database is on-prem

Tags: azure-data-factory, on-premises-instances

I'm using a lookup activity to extract data from an on-premise SAP Hana database, how can I check whether all the required columns are available and check the datatype without using data flow because it won't work on the on-premise data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **query option in the lookup activity**. Give the below query in it to get the **Schema(Column name and Data type)** of the particular SAP HANA table.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE_NAME FROM TABLE_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME= '<Table_name>' ORDER BY POSITION
```

Go through the examples provided in this [blog](http://sapbasisinfo.com/blog/2018/05/10/get-description-for-a-hana-table-instead-of-usage-desc/) by **@sapbasisinfo** about this query.

**(OR)**

You can try queries from this [blog](https://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/hana-database-table-columns-list-using-sqlscript.aspx) by **@kodyaz**  which gives similar results.

If you execute the above query in lookup, that will give the result in an array of objects like below.

For demonstration of the result, I have given similar query in SQL database.

[image]

You can use this array to check the columns and data types of your SAP HANA table. But you should have data about your expected column names and data types to compare with these.